# How to insert variables values into html input text fields?

Tags: php, html

is there a way in Php to modify the value of a html input text field dynamic? I want to display data from db an thought input text fields would be the best way.

F.e.
I get an array from a soap server and want to put the values into different text input fields, how can I do this? Do I have to create a complete new site or can I dynamically insert the values to fields on the same site?

Regards
Ismir

Comment: If all you want to do is display this data, an `<input..>` field is not the way to go. Input fields are there to accept data from the user, not display data to the user. Use standard html.

Comment: Again with the upvote **on a bad question** Please stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in `array $arr` and you can immediately use it to create the HTML output.

your HTML could look like:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $arr['firstname']; ?>">
```

If your HTML is already on screen and you want to update the screen with the new values of `$arr` you will have to use AJAX/javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Indeed the html is already on screen. Thk u, that answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

All above answers are good but to prevent a warning you must enclose it into a isset().

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php if(isset($arr['firstname'])){echo $arr['firstname'];}else{echo '';} ?>">
```

Or use the shortcode below:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo isset($arr['firstname']) ? $arr['firstname'] : ''; ?>">
```